# The requested address is not valid in its context at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

Tags: socketexception

I had purchased **third party control** for verify email addres From **Cobisi.com.** and i configured mail server ip address and port no. please see belowe.

```
EmailVerifier verifier = new EmailVerifier();
verifier.LocalHostFqdn = "mail.xyz.com";
verifier.LocalSenderAddress = "test@xyz.com";
verifier.LocalSmtpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.9"), 25);
var result = verifier.Verify(objContact.ContactValue, VerificationLevel.Mailbox);
if (result.IsSuccess)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

But when i run this code then give exception like "The requested address is not valid in its context at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) "